# Invalid on demand test run run id 0 error when running pipeline test

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm running automation tests through my Azure DevOps pipeline. The tests run successfully in one environment but when it goes to run in the next environment I get the following errors:

> [error]Input validation failed with exception: Invalid on demand test run id 0. Has to be greater than 0.
>
> [error]Error: The process
>   'd:\a_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.153.9\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe'
>   failed with exit code 1

Tried to play around with the config but nothing seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi there Jdocker123. I think your question is a little difficult to answer, without knowing some more detail about your situation. Could you describe what technology you are using for automation tests (e.g. junit, or cucumber), what your environments are, and how the test runner is called from your pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post but I ran into the same problem and I think found a resolution.

Some of the things that helped me below:

1. you have to have a release pipeline that consumes a build pipeline as an artifact if you want to run automated tests from the Test Plans section of Azure.
2. there are 3 test options you can use in the release pipeline:
   "Test plan", "Test run", or "Test assemblies".
   I think the only one that works from the Test Plans section of Azure is the "Test run" option.  If you use another option you can get similar errors.
   Similarly, when you are triggering the pipeline from the Pipelines section you must use the "Test assemblies" or "Test plan" options.
3. Double check the Test Case -> Automated Association tab to ensure that it looks correct.  I had a case where we changed the name of our DLL and that broke all of our Automated Associations.  Because of that we kept getting errors such as above.

That was a tougher one to catch because it had nothing to do with the pipeline itself, but the Automated Associations all had to be re-done via the "Associate to Test Case" functionality in VS Test Explorer and the associations on the Azure Test Cases themselves.

hope that helps someone in the future!